Tolerate network errors when uploading to Azure Blob Storage
I have an ASP.NET Core application that accepts file uploads via the API (mp4 files). I want to read data in chunks from the input stream and write them to Azure Blob Storage as they come in.
The files can be really large, and if there is a network error I want to at least have what has been written so far.
If I use the standard BlobClient.UploadAsync(stream) there are zero bytes written if the upload fails after 99% for example.
I'm trying to read from a file just to get a proof of concept, and I have found that the following works, but I wonder if there is a better way?
var blobUriWithSas = new Uri($"{storageAccountUrl}/?{sasToken}");
var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(blobUriWithSas);
var blobContainerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("container");
var blockBlobClient = blobContainerClient.GetBlockBlobClient("file.mp4");

var blockIds = new List<string>();

using var fileStream = File.OpenRead("file.mp4");
var buffer = new byte[2048*10];
int bytesRead;
int blockId = 0;

while ((bytesRead = await fileStream.ReadAsync(buffer)) > 0)
{
    var blockIdBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(BitConverter.GetBytes(blockId++));
    blockIds.Add(blockIdBase64);

    using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

    // Upload the block
    await blockBlobClient.StageBlockAsync(blockIdBase64, memoryStream);

    if (blockId % 50 == 0)
    {
        // Commit the blocks now and then
        await blockBlobClient.CommitBlockListAsync(blockIds);
    }
}

// Commit the blocks when all is done
await blockBlobClient.CommitBlockListAsync(blockIds);


It might slow things down but you can always commit your block list after each block upload. Then read the block list before uploading the next block, upload the block and recommit the uploaded block list.


I'm trying to read from a file just to get a proof of concept, and I have found that the following works, but I wonder if there is a better way?

I agree with Gaurav Mantri's comment, you can commit your block list after each block upload. Before uploading the next block, read the block list, upload the block, and then recommit the updated block list.
However, this approach may slow down the overall upload process due to the additional overhead of committing the block list after each block upload.
Code:
        var storageAccountUrl = "xxx";
        var sasToken = "xxxxxx";
        var containerName = "xxx";
        var fileName = "xxxx";

        var blobUriWithSas = new Uri($"{storageAccountUrl}/?{sasToken}");
        var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(blobUriWithSas);
        var blobContainerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
        var blockBlobClient = blobContainerClient.GetBlockBlobClient(fileName);

        var blockIds = new List<string>();

        try
        {
            // Attempt to get the existing block list
            var existingBlockList = await blockBlobClient.GetBlockListAsync(BlockListTypes.Committed);
            foreach (var block in existingBlockList.Value.CommittedBlocks)
            {
                blockIds.Add(block.Name);
            }
        }
        catch (Azure.RequestFailedException ex) when (ex.ErrorCode == "BlobNotFound")
        {
            // If the blob is not found, continue with an empty block list
            Console.WriteLine("Blob not found. Starting a new upload.");
        }

        using var fileStream = File.OpenRead("file.mp4");
        var buffer = new byte[4 * 1024 * 1024]; // 4 MB buffer
        int bytesRead;
        int blockId = 0;
        const int maxRetries = 3;

        while ((bytesRead = await fileStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            var blockIdBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(BitConverter.GetBytes(blockId++));

            using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

            // Upload the block with retry logic
            bool uploaded = false;
            int attempt = 0;

            while (!uploaded && attempt < maxRetries)
            {
                try
                {
                    await blockBlobClient.StageBlockAsync(blockIdBase64, memoryStream);
                    uploaded = true;
                }
                catch (Exception ex) when (attempt < maxRetries)
                {
                    attempt++;
                    Console.WriteLine($"Attempt {attempt} to upload block {blockIdBase64} failed: {ex.Message}");
                    await Task.Delay(2000); // Optional: delay before retry
                }
            }

            if (uploaded)
            {
                // Add the successfully uploaded block ID to the list
                blockIds.Add(blockIdBase64);

                // Commit the block list after each block upload
                await blockBlobClient.CommitBlockListAsync(blockIds);
            }
        }

        // Final commit (optional if already committed after each block)
        await blockBlobClient.CommitBlockListAsync(blockIds);

The above code uploads a file to Azure Blob Storage in chunks by making use of StageBlockAsync method in AzureSDK to upload each block and the CommitBlockListAsync method to commit the blocks. In the event of an error, the upload is repeated up to three times before it is ultimately committed.
Portal:

Nonetheless, this approach could result in slower overall upload though because committing block list per block adds overhead.
Reference:
BlockBlobClient.CommitBlockList Method (Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized) - Azure for .NET Developers | Microsoft Learn
